# Problema en Unity al iniciar nuevo proyecto

Tags: unity3d, unity

tengo la version de Unity instalada 2018.2.2f1.

Cuando creo un proyecto nuevo, me genera todo esto.

[image: Cuando creo un proyecto nuevo, me genera todo esto]

El problema que tengo es que cuando añado un script a un objeto de unity (pongamos un cubo) me da error de compilacion ya que no encuentra las dlls que deberian estar. Concretamente no me compila nada de los proyectos que comienzan por Unity*.

[image: Aqui la imagen donde se ve que abro el script asociado a un cubo y en la ventana output los errores]

Si es un proyecto nuevo como puede ser que las referencias existan pero los ficheros donde apuntan estas no?
Gracias
Saludos
Jose.

Comment: ese codigo no esta bien :(... si quieres crear un script te recomiendo que lo metas en un metodo primero.

Answer (score 0):

Todos esos mensajes son sobre el TextMeshPro, fíjate que en Unity arriba a la izquierda tenes un "Package Manager", ahí podes actualizar todos tus paquetes.
Otra cosa que podes intentar es borrar ese script y darle a Play a Unity a ver si aun así te tira algún error.
Si tampoco funciona, avisa y te seguimos ayudando, si no, otra opción mas rápida y menos educativa es borrar por completo Unity y Unity Hub y volver a descargar "Unity Hub" y desde ahí instalas una versión de Unity.